# What is the structure of the $data array in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module

I am studying/developing a module for Magento 2.
I created an observer for a specific event and now I'd like to collect some data such as Customer information and Product information. I know I can use the magic metods `get*Something*` to navigate through the $data array and get specific values but how do I know what values are stored in the array? Is there a resource/documentation that lists at least the default parameters? I know it contains a lot of custom parameters from the different modules.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found a way to read the content of the data passed during the execution of Magento via xdebug.

[Here is an interesting article](http://mageclass.com/how-to-configure-xdebug-for-magento-2-development/) on how to do it on Sublime and JetBrains (PHPstorm or IntelliJ).

Thank you Khoa for your great explanation though!

[image: Debug screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Like many big applications, Magento uses Object Relational Mapping(ORM) approach (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). We will use Model to get the data Object. The Model of Magento can be divided into two types: **Simple Model and EAV model.**

1) **Simple Model**: one object to one table. The attributes of Object map each fields of our table. So, in this case, when calling `$yourObjectModel->getData()`, it will return the field values of your table.

2) **Entity Attribute Value(EAV)**: (really complicated) This used to present the entity with a dynamic number of attributes.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-7.html

**For the EAV Model, we also can get the attributes from `$objectEAVModel->getData()` to check the current attributes.

---

Magento ORM uses a PHP's magic class methods- `Magento\Framework\DataObject::__call`-  for Setter/Getter attribute wrapper. This is an answer to the question why we can use `getData()` or `getData('attribute')` or `getCustomAttribute()`.

Comment: This is some really interesting information! Thank you for your answer! But what I am trying to understand is how do I know what I CAN get or set when  my observer is triggered by an event? `$observer->getData()->getWHAT?();` I'm not sure if I'm totally clear here...

Comment: Thank you! I just came home from mine, so I will look it up tomorrow morning! Appreciate your help!

Comment: Tomorrow, I will answer your question. I was busy.

Comment: All right! Thank you I am still experimenting with it... I am trying to dump the content of `$observer->getData()` to see the structure... but it's HUGE... I think I am missing some concept.

Comment: You should take a look here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html and http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/events-and-observers-a-magento-tutorial/